# What is the proper way to review a late answer from a new user that doesn't add anything?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to reviewing and in relation to that I have a question regarding how to handle an answer to an [old question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/disable-saving-to-icloud-in-mountain-lion) with an already accepted answer like this one:

[image]

It's an answer to a question from 2012. The answer is *technically* not wrong but it doesn't really add any value. Since it's a new user she might just not entire grasp the StackExchange system yet.

Do I:

- Helpfully comment that it might be inappropriate?
- Ignore it?
- Down-vote?
- Flag it?
- Something else?

Tried browsing meta to see if I could find an answer but with no luck.

Any guidance would be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New answers to old questions can be anything from spam to gem, so it's kind of difficult to give a simple answer on that. But in general the same rules apply both for current and for old topics

- if it is inappropriate or out of line -> flag
- if it is just wrong, incomplete or confusing -> downvote
- if you think the OP can/should improve it, add a comment with some followup questions

In the case you mentioned it seems to have been meant as a comment to the accepted answer, something which is actually helpful because Mavericks brought some very welcome changes regarding iCloud document syncing. So flagging it for moderator attention would be a good way to handle that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the guidelines!

Comment: I do tend to comment as well as down vote to give the user an idea - even if iy is just pointing them to a FAQ

Comment: Age should not be a major factor when reviewing content, primary consideration should be the same as if it was a new answer to a new question.